# Launcher doesn't re-appear after I select auto-hide

Tags: unity, 12.04, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launcher auto-hides but does not come back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145530/launcher-auto-hides-but-does-not-come-back)

I have 12.04 version. When I select ON option for auto-hide the launcher I can't make it re-appear. It doesn't matter what kind of "hot spot" reveal location I select or which reveal sensitivity level I select.