# Launcher auto-hides but does not come back

Tags: 12.04, launcher

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. If I switch on "Auto-hide launcher", it hides but does not reveal with the pointer, and only comes back on switching off auto-hide.

Comment: Does it appear when you use the Super key?

Comment: Which version of Unity are you using - [3D or 2D](http://askubuntu.com/q/62001/18612)? Also, are you running on bare hardware or inside a VirtualBox session? I found a couple bugs that might possibly be relevant ([Bug 989477](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/989477), [Bug 971018](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/971018)) but I can't be sure which you're experiencing unless you provide some more information. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you're using a multi-screen setup.  I have seen this issue as well.  I just use the super key to work around it.  If you put the launcher on the left-most screen it evidences much less often

Comment: I have this problem, too, and I am not on multi-screen.

Comment: Bug in unity CONFIRMED https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/970038

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton Thank you for the hints. For all those using Ubuntu in **VirtualBox** disable **"Mouse integration"** option if you want Unity launcher to re-appear when Auto-Hide is enabled. Tested with VirtualBox version 5.0.22 r108108 and Ubuntu 16.04. More info about this issue can be found on the related [bug report page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/971018).

Comment: That was exactly my problem, thanks @informatik01

Comment: @AlexanderFradiani You're welcome!

Answer (score 29):

Thanks to "Warrioring 64". I found my solution in replies to BUG 9894477.
Launcher reappears:-

1. By pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. By pressing <kbd>super</kbd> key.
3. By striking the left side with the pointer 3/4 times quickly.
4. By moving your pointer towards the left end and when you reach the left end, don't stop and just keep moving left (as if you're trying to push the mouse out of the screen).

Comment: What you pointed out at 3. lets me assume that it could be solved via [editing the Launcher Reveal Pressure with CCSM](http://askubuntu.com/a/138850/46531). Did you try that?

Comment: (1.) works for this same problem in `Scientific Linux`

Comment: Amusingly, this bug persists in 14.04 and I had no access to any apps; I had to google on my phone for a solution. Which was to hit alt-f1 and then disable auto-hide, as it's broken.

Comment: Still an issue with 15.10.

Comment: Still an issue with 16.04.3 LTS. Only 2. worked for me (hitting the 'Windows' button).

Answer (score 5):

Could it be [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/970038)?

Install CompizConfig Settings Manager [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] and start CCSM. Edit `Ubuntu Unity Plugin` and inside the `Experimental` Tab set `Launcher Reveal Pressure` to "1" (instead of "20" - default).

[image]

But be aware: *CCSM is an advanced tool. Use with caution. This tool allows you to deeply configure Compiz's settings. Some options may be incompatible with each other. Unless used with care, it is possible to be left with an unusable desktop.*

Comment: This solved it for me. Changing settings in appearance does not work.

Comment: Did not work for me on Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: worked for me ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

With Ubuntu 12.04, my launcher stopped revealing when I pushed my mouse to the left side of the screen. This happened after I changed several CompizConfig Settings Manager settings to completely resolve a "sticky-edges" problem among multiple displays.

The problem was that I had set the "edge stop velocity" to 1. After I returned this value to its default (65), my launcher behaved normally again. The edge stop velocity description reads, "The maximum velocity at which the mouse will be stopped," so I think my launcher wasn't revealing because my pointer was always moving to fast to register as a "stop" on the left side of the screen. Whatever the reason, play with this value if the launcher isn't popping up and everything else seems normal.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Setting --> Appearance --> Behavior

Now you can enable/disable auto-hide and Reveal Sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.
Go to System Settings > 'Appearance'.
Select the tab 'Behaviour' and switch `OFF` the fade out function.

Alternatively adjust the sensibility of the reveal. The higher the bar, the faster you have to scroll to the side to let the Launcher appear.

Comment: I think your answer is essentially the same as Shekhar's but the descriptions used for naigating the GUI do not match the names used in the English version of Ubuntu. Please consider editing your answer to improve it.

Answer (score -2):

Well i faced this problem too...The solution I followed??

This might not be the exact solution you want but if nothing else works,you may use this-

I loved the dodge window feature more...I brought it back through compiz...

If you also like it or wish to add and use it, do the following-

1. Install CompizConfigurationManager via the SoftwareCenter if you do not have it
2. enter the following commands in the terminal one by one-

> ```
> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped    
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
> ```

You will find the feature in the "Ubuntu Unity Plugin" option.

1:

[image: plugin1]

2:

[image: plugin2]