# Allow windows to be completely full-screen in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, fullscreen

I remember on 16.04 I had to change settings so that windows could be completely full-screen. On 18.04, I can't figure it out. The menu bar on the left is always visible. I am looking for "zen-mode" where a given application can be completely full-screen, anyone know how to do that in 18.04?

Comment: Is your issue only with the "*bar on the left*" (Ubuntu dock)? It can be (auto-)hidden.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/457614/480481) tells how to auto-hide Ubuntu dock. Following [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720617/how-do-i-hide-gnome-3-panel) you'll be able to auto-hide the top-bar. Then all your windows will be *completely* full-screen.

Comment: I actually hide both Dock and top bar. Dock options are already explained in another thread. For top bar I use Hide top bar extension.