# launcher not coming in screen

Tags: launcher

Launcher has vanished from my desktop. I can now see only the desktop icon in my screen and right click option gives me usual setting option only.

Please suggest what needs to be checked? Has some package got corrupted or services needs to be restarted?

Before this issue came up, launcher was working fine and I was working with application download of some graphic card, VM ware , thunderbird configuration and browsing.

Thanks,

Prashant

Comment: The question need some additions. What version of Ubuntu you use ? What kernel you have installed ? As you said , I count on VMWare modules fault. What version of VMWare you installed ?

Answer (score 0):

May you not do proper search, there are some answer which may solve your problem

[no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/a/76951/67654)

[Launcher auto-hides](https://askubuntu.com/a/146991/67654)

[Ubuntu 12.10 shows no launcher or menu](https://askubuntu.com/a/209840/67654)